# Generate polygons after marching squares in parallel

Tags: computational-geometry, polygon, 2d-graphics

I've implemented the marching squares algorithm following Wikipedia's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares. The output I got is a set of edges, to which each contouring cell contributes 0, 1, or 4 edges.

How do I modify or post-process this algorithm to obtain a set of distinct polygons from these edges?
Oh and I want to do so in parallel.

I guess the sequential approach would be to pick an edge and follow it until it comes back to the beginning, then move on to another unprocessed edge.

Comment: what should your output look like? list of points and a list of connections (from point to point)? Or adjacency list of points? What do you mean with parallel? Like executing in parallel some code for each vertex? I would recommend, to give us an example.

Comment: i would like to output a list of polygons. a polygons is a list of vertices in counterclockwise order. in parallel means with multi-threading. i would like an algorithm that is parallizable.